What possible sensors can be used in a digital pen and what algorithms would be suitable if the letter recognition is not needed?
I have a project regrading a smart electronic pen and for that I need to know what possible sensors can be used , I don't want any letter recognition and just proper sketching through with just perfectly align with actual hand writing.
What algorithms and sensors can be used ? Kindly help.

just proper sketching through with just perfectly align with actual hand writing ... what does that mean?

I mean what sensors can I gather and make a smart digital pen with which I can write on a surface and I can see that writing on the screen. I don't want any letter recognition. I just need perfect writing on screen just as my hand will do on surface.

Do you want to /implement/ a Wacom tablet, or /use/ a Wacom tablet (for various values of "Wacom")? If "use", you need to check the manufacturer's documentation for whichever specific product you're using. If you're implementing and engineering, it's a more interesting answer, but we need you to clarify first.
